# Tensorflow replacement for numpy tostring

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am building tfrecords out of image files found in `img_fpaths`, which is a list.

I try to do everything using `tf.data.Dataset` so as to make it fast using parallel calls and prefetch options.

Before running the full job I am making some tests in a notebook to verify the that the pipeline works as expected. In my mind it looks like: read image file --> decode image content --> convert image content to binary -->decode raw binary data (this last thing is for the test only, I will replace it with code to save into tfrecords once it works)

Here is my code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_fpaths)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda fpath: tf.read_file(fpath))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda img_bytes: tf.image.decode_image(img_bytes))

dataset = dataset.map(lambda img: tf.as_string(tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32)))

# the following linke is for the test only, once this works I know how to save it as tfrecords
dataset = dataset.map(lambda img_bytes: tf.decode_raw(img_bytes, out_type=tf.float32))
```

After this I run the following code which does not throw any error if I remove the last `dataset.map`operation.

```
pair = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    var = sess.run(pair)
```

But since it is not removed it throws the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

~/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: DecodeRaw requires input strings to all be the same size, but element 471 has size 10 != 9
 [[Node: DecodeRaw = DecodeRaw[little_endian=true, out_type=DT_FLOAT](arg0)]]
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext_23 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, []], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator_23)]]
```

I now I can convert a numpy array to binary using the `.tostring()` method, so I wonder if there is a replacement in TensorFlow